# Cakephp view.ctp error: cakephp Object #<HTMLCollection> has no method 'submit

Tags: cakephp

I have created a function like this to delete the record:

```
echo $this->Form->postLink('<i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>', 
array('action' => 'delete',$distance['Distance']['id'], 'Distance'), 
array('confirm' => 'Are you sure?', 'class' => 'btn btn-danger', 'escape' => false));
```

It should call the function delete in the controller passing two parameters.

But I get this type of error in chrome console:

**cakephp Object # has no method 'submit'**

Previously it was working and now the delete button sometimes works and sometimes it does not.

Controller code is:

```
public function delete($id, $model) {

         $this->loadModel($model);
         $this->Session->setFlash($id +" " + $model);

        if ($this->request->is('get')) {
            throw new MethodNotAllowedException();
        }

        if ($this->$model->delete($id)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('The item has been deleted');
            if($model == "Project" || $model == "Car"){
                 $this->redirect(array('action' => 'preferences'));
            }else{
                $this->redirect(array('action' => $model.'s'));
            }

        }
       }
```

Comment: What is the problem here actually, it works fine for me

Comment: The problem is that the delete function in the controller is not being invoked because of this error I think

Comment: May i see your controller code

Comment: Sure you are not using a postLink() inside a form?

Comment: Well I've added the form: <?php echo $this->Form->create();?> and also  <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?> but it does not help

Comment: @harlejus I am getting this same error. In my instance, it only happens on a PC browser (tested on FF and Chrome) but not on the Mac equivalents. It seems to be related to the presence of a flash message. Is any of this consistent with your situation?

Comment: @harlejus BTW, `postLink()` should NOT be used inside another form.

Answer (score 0):

try to work with

> $this->Form->submit() instead of postLink();